# How to create an EditorFor a collection and avoid doing a loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

For example:

**Model**

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Editor Template for Person (PersonEditor.cshtml):**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Person

@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)
<label>First Name</label>    
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.FirstName)
<label>Last Name</label>    
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.LastName)
<br />
```

On my main page, I want to be able to do the following:

```
@model IList<MvcApplication1.Models.Person>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{       
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x,"PersonEditor")    
}
```

And have all the elements in the form, generate the proper names automatically; instead of having to loop through the collection as I am doing now:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x=>Model[i],"PersonEditor")    
    }   
}
```

The form elements must contain the following format:

```
<input name="[0].ID" type="text" value="Some ID" />
<input name="[0].FirstName" type="text" value="Some value" />
<input name="[1].ID" type="text" value="Some x" />
<input name="[1].FirstName" type="text" value="Some y" />
```

And so on...

Because in my controller, I expect to receive an `IList<Person>` when the form posts pack.

**Can I eliminate that for loop completely?**

## EDIT

Right now, when I simply do `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x)` (without the loop, in other words), I get this exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MvcApplication1.Models.Person[]', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Person'.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038392/editorfor-ienumerablet-with-templatename

Comment: @Zabavsky Wonderful!, believe me, I searched through SO for over an hour and I never hit that question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the same template for both `IEnumerable<T>` and `T`. The Templating is smart enough to enumerate the IEnumerable, but you will need to rename the editor template to match the type name. Then you should be able to use

```
@model IList<MvcApplication1.Models.Person>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{       
    @Html.EditorForModel()    
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like a template named anything other than the type name will throw an exception

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MvcApplication1.Models.Person[]', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Person'

Comment: How about with using `@Html.EditorForModel()`? Do you get the same issue?

Comment: I must be doing something stupid then because when I do `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x)` I get this exception: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Person[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Person'.`

Comment: Yep, same exception as before: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Person[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Person'`

Comment: My bad. I've just run up a demo to test it and you're right. Looks like in inconsistency in the framework as if you change the EditorTemplate name to `Person` and simple use `@Html.EditorForModel()` you'll get the expected result. So it looks like it doens't work with non default named template names. Will update answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. I had no idea that the template name had to match the Model name exactly.