# ASP.NET MVC Editor Template Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

After having problems getting a Razor View to render a ViewModel with an embedded `IEnumerable` I came across the following post:
[View Model IEnumerable<> property is coming back null (not binding) from post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915395/view-model-ienumerable-property-is-coming-back-null-not-binding-from-post-me/9915477#9915477)

I implemented the suggested solution using an editor template but my View was only displaying the first property in the embedded `IEnumerable`. I implemented both solutions from the above post but the one with the `EditorFor` template is not working for me. My view displays only the `ID`property.

Does anyone have any ideas why the soution with the editor template may not be working for my setup? I have implemented it exactly as suggested.

Comment: Please actually include some of the code from your setup. Otherwise, we are only making assumptions.

Comment: Nope, no idea... because you didn't include any code.

Comment: all the code is in the original post......not point cutting and pasting it. As I said I implemented both suggested solutions. The one with the for loop worked but the Editor template one only displayed the first property of the enumerable property. Anyway, I will move on with the for loop and wonder why the Editor Template did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is only displaying the first item then your template is not being picked up in the EditorTemplates folder.

Define your template in the EditorFor extension method like below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "NameofEditorTemplate")
```

Answer (score 1):

For using Editor Template consider the following **tips**:

1. You have to place templates inside *EditorTemplates* folder in
   *Views* folder.
2. You should use `EditorFor` HTML helper to call appropriate template
   (when you have specific model to view, It will find the desired
   template automatically, otherwise you have to hint the engine,
   whether by an argument in `EditorFor` or using `[UIHint]` attribute
   in the model. Look at [Extending Editor Templates for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/)
3. Use Simple models inside templates like `string`, `DateTime?`
4. For working with `IEnumerable` models for template, consider a very important tip available in [EditorFor IEnumerable with TemplateName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038392/editorfor-ienumerablet-with-templatename).